# Is delete a function or reserved keyword in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I was working on a Todo List built with Vue, and I wanted to integrate a delete function. I wanted to name my function `delete()` which would trigger on the click of a span tag. This is my code:

`<span style="cursor:pointer" @click="delete()"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></span>`

But I noticed that unlike other functions, delete() was having different syntax highlighting, and where I wrote the closing parenthesis, there was a little error like this:

```
[vue/no-parsing-error]
Parsing error: Unexpected token ).eslint-plugin-vue
```

So this is my question: Is `delete` some reserved function or keyword in Vue or JavaScript which I can take advantage of in my app?

Comment: it's an [operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

Comment: *delete* is a [*reserved word*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-keywords-and-reserved-words) that is also a keyword and is the identifier used for the [*delete* unary operator](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-delete-operator).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes `delete` is a reserved keyword which is used to delete object field :

```js
let user = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 27
}

console.log('before delete age field ', user)
delete user.age
console.log('after delete age field ', user)
```

Comment: It is important to note that `delete` should not be used on Vue 2 reactive data because such operation is not detected by Vue. [Vue.delete()](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-delete) function should be used instead. This does not apply to Vue 3...

Answer (score 3):

I think **delete** is a keyword in JavaScript.
You should check this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete?retiredLocale=vi